# Spring boot rejects body when sent by site but not with postman

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Hey so Im working with spring boot and something weird is occurring. I want to make a post request to my springboot server, I am successful when i do it via postman but fails when I do it via my website. I tried to change it to different HTTP requests and data models but i get the same error. There seems to be no differences in the bodies that Ive sent from what Ive seen and tested. Error stacktrace is in web request (all the way down).

**My controller code**

```
    @CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
    System.out.println(body);
    ResponseModel responseModel;
    ProfileResource login = new ProfileResource();
    login.setUsername(body.get("Username"));
    login.setPassword(body.get("Password"));

    // other code..

    responseModel.setData(login);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseModel, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

**My JS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#LoginButtonID").click(function(){
    if($('#LoginButtonID').is(':visible')) {
        var link  = "http://localhost:9024/login/auth";
        var body = "{"+
            "\"Username\":\""+document.getElementById("UserNameID").value+"\", " +
            "\"Password\":\""+document.getElementById("PasswordID").value+"\"" +
            "}";
        console.log(body);
        sendRequest(link,'POST',body);
        console.log(data)
        if(data.response.toString()===("valid and successful")){
            localStorage.setItem("username",document.getElementById("UserNameID").value);
            window.location.href = "../html/UserPages/Welcome.html";
        }else if(data.response.toString()===("failed to authenticate")){
            alert("failed to login");
        }
    }
})
});

function sendRequest(link, type, body) {
    // http request sent to the server in hopes that it will take it
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(type, link, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // once the request was sent and received we then make use of the response
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 202 ) {
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("data: " + data.response.toString());
        }else if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 401 ){
            console.log("Auth failed")
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);            }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

**Postman Response:**

```
{
"successful": true,
"responseCode": 0,
"response": "valid and successful",
"data": {
    "name": null,
    "password": null,
    "username": "a",
    "email": null
}
}
console (IDE) output:
{Username=a, Password=a}
```

**Web Request**

```
login.js:12 {"Username":"a", "Password":"a"}
login.js:47 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
sendRequest @ login.js:47
(anonymous) @ login.js:13
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5201
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5009
login.js:65 POST http://localhost:9024/login/auth 500
sendRequest @ login.js:65
(anonymous) @ login.js:13
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5201
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5009
login.js:14 undefined
login.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (login.js:15)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)

    Console (IDE) output:
2019-10-06 04:36:56.730  WARN 24332 --- [nio-9024-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"Username":"a", "Password":"a"}'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"Username":"a", "Password":"a"}')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

Comment: share your html as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if your response JSON contains the `response` field. 
As per logs, the response received is `{"Username":"a", "Password":"a"}` whereas in your JS code you are doing `data.response.toString()`, as response is undefined. You are getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined` error.

I tried following code, it worked on my system:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LoginButtonID").click(function(){
            var link  = "http://localhost:9024/login/auth";
            var body = "{"+
                "\"Username\":\""+document.getElementById("UserNameID").value+"\", " +
                "\"Password\":\""+document.getElementById("PasswordID").value+"\"" +
                "}";
            sendRequest(link,'POST',body);

            if(data.response.toString()===("valid and successful")){
                localStorage.setItem("username",document.getElementById("UserNameID").value);
                alert("done!")
            }else if(data.response.toString()===("failed to authenticate")){
                alert("failed to login");
            }
    })
});

function sendRequest(link, type, body) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(type, link, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 202 ) {
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }else if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 401 ){
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);            }
    }
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

Controller code:

```
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
@PostMapping("auth")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
    // sending some response for the sake of testing
    body.put ("response","valid and successful");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an asynchronous request. You're using jquery already, it provides this functionality in [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), no need to use javascript's built-in XMLHttpRequest.